# How to remove SKSpriteNodes once there is a complete row? (like tetris)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am building a game similar to Tetris in the sense that there are falling obstacles that land on the ground and pile up. I am trying to figure out a way to remove all of the SKSpriteNodes from the bottom row, once it is full. Essentially, I need to remove all of the nodes that are below a Y value, but only once there are 5 (there are 5 in a row) below that Y value.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Here is some code:

```
func createWall() {

    let wall = SKSpriteNode()

    let random = (arc4random_uniform(5)+1)

    wall.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.width / 10 * (2*(CGFloat(random))-1), self.frame.height + 100)
    wall.size = wallSize
    wall.color = wallColor

    wall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: wall.size)
    wall.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Wall
    wall.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Hero | PhysicsCatagory.Ground
    wall.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Hero | PhysicsCatagory.Ground | PhysicsCatagory.Wall
    wall.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    wall.physicsBody?.dynamic = true

    if random == 1 {
        numberInColumnOne += 1
    } else if random == 2 {
        numberInColumnTwo += 1
    } else if random == 3 {
        numberInColumnThree += 1
    } else if random == 4 {
        numberInColumnFour += 1
    } else if random == 5 {
        numberInColumnFive += 1
    }

    self.addChild(wall)

    print(numberInColumnOne)
    print(numberInColumnTwo)
    print(numberInColumnThree)
    print(numberInColumnFour)
    print(numberInColumnFive)

}


override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    let spawn = SKAction.runBlock({
        () in

        self.createWall()

    })


    let delay = SKAction.waitForDuration(3)
    let spawnDelay = SKAction.sequence([spawn, delay])
    let spawnDelayForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(spawnDelay)

    self.runAction(spawnDelayForever)

}
```

Comment: It depends on how you have set up your scene. Is each falling shape one node or are they a group of multiple nodes, one for each square?

Comment: You must add some code to your question, it's too broad.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tutorial which goes through the complete process of building a Tetris game in swift, I think it uses Swift 1 though so be careful about that, but it should contain the information you need:

https://www.bloc.io/swiftris-build-your-first-ios-game-with-swift#!/

Other than providing that reference, the rest depends on how you have implemented your blocks and grid system, If you can provide more information I'll update the answer.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: Generally, I would. But the part about detecting a full line depends on the rest of the foundation work beneath it, so it would be alot to copy. Also the link has been active for a long time and is part of a companies blog, so I doubt it will be removed any time soon. But of course, if there are any issues I'll gladly remove the answer